# Force Safari to Open a Universal Link in a Native App from the Home Screen

Tags: ios, safari, ios-universal-links

I have a webpage whose URL is represented by a Universal Link and opens in a native app when clicked from messages. However, when users save this webpage to their home screen, the page opens in Safari, even though the app is installed. It does display the app hint and "Open" button at the top of the page, though.

Is there a way to force Safari to bypass this and go directly to the app when the link is opened from the home screen?